# ios firebase database get key of value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Sorry newbie here. I can't seem to find any solution that helps me get the following information from the firebase realtime database (see image)

[image: orange rectangle marks structure of data and data to be retrieve]

*orange rectangle marks structure of data and data to be retrieve*

This is my current code

```
ref.child("locations").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children{
            let valueD = child as! DataSnapshot
            let keyD = valueD.key
            let value1 = valueD.value
            print(value1)
            // This gives "-L-other letters" = 0 (but I only want the string without "= 0")
})
```

Is there any way I can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `locations` is the root of what you show in the screenshot, you're only looping over the first level of children (`37d42...` etc). To get the keys you marked, you need to loop one level deeper. So:

```
ref.child("locations").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children{
        for grandchild in child.children{
            let valueD = grandchild as! DataSnapshot
            let keyD = valueD.key
            let value1 = valueD.value
            print(keyD)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Ahh I see :o This worked for me thank you very much!