# Request result structure firebasedatabase Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Looking to retrieve value of custom class from a snap in swift like i do in java , i use Firebasedecoder .
Works fine but i need the following structure

```
{

username = uiii;
email = test@rom.com

..}
```

If i make ordered requests like `.queryOrdered(ByCHild:email).queryEqual("uiii")`, i get  the resquest with a previous node :

```
{

"hjhj"= {
username = uiii;
email = test@rom.com

..} }
```

Looking for a way to either remove the uneccessary values or to have the correct snap structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, if you have extra data at the same level and that makes `decodeFirebase` crash, you still can use it:

```
let value = snapshot.value 
let modifiedValue:NSMutableDictionary = (value as AnyObject).mutableCopy() as! MutableDictionary
```

You then can remove elements by key: `modifiedValue.removeObject(forKey: test)`
and then apply decode.

Comment: There is no reason at all to use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift.

Comment: @ vadaian : I woulkd even say : there s no reason at all not to use NSMutable...

Comment: one more comment for the upvoter( or censor as you see it i vevn forgot to thank you for censoring me , my bad

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

To get to the individual node(s) in the result, you need to loop over `snapshot.children`, as shown in the Firebase documentation on [listening for value events on a list of children](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events).

Also see:

- previous questions about [looping over children](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bswift%5D+loop+children)
- [Get the data from all children in firebase using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56638755/get-the-data-from-all-children-in-firebase-using-swift/56640036#56640036)
- [Firebase queryOrderedByChild() method not giving sorted data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222128/firebase-queryorderedbychild-method-not-giving-sorted-data/39229537#39229537) for an alternative if you want to only receive a single child node and only once

Comment: I have only one result as planned. The issue is the structure of the result i can not handle . I tried to loop like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50847960/ios-firebase-database-get-key-of-value but i get errors saying NSEnumerator.element has no value for ... This is more the data structure that i don t know how to handle than the result itself

Comment: It doesn't matter how many results you have planned, if you're using a query the result is a list and you'll need to loop over the children. If you are having a hard time making the code from the links work, edit your question (there's a link right under it) to show the [minimal, complete/standalone code that anyone can run to reproduce where you go stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

custom class USER with all values in the pictures

import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import CodableFirebase

//knowing the userid , clean beautiful result with Firebasedecoder

func cleanResultWithCodebableFirebase(){

```
      ref.child("3oleg").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
           guard let value = snapshot.value else { return }
           do {
               let user = try FirebaseDecoder().decode(User.self, from: value)
               print(user.getUser_id())
               
           } catch let error {
               print(error)
           }
       })
```

}

not knowing userID dirty result

func customwithdirtylists(){

let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: Strings.field_username).queryEqual(toValue: "uiiii")
query.observeSingleEvent(
of: .value, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in

```
   for child in snapshot.children {

     let childSnapshot = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: (child as AnyObject).key)

     for grandchild in childSnapshot.children{
         let grandchildSnapshot = childSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: (grandchild as AnyObject).key)
         //possible from here to get the key and values of each element of the custom class

         
     }
     

   }
```

})

}

This is the code i use in both cases, direct request or when ordered . No list visible when direct with the help of firebase decode .Ugly way to rebuild custom class thru looping . I m sure there are more elegant ways to do it especially when all i need is just remove one value of the direct result to have a clean result